# SQL Fiddle Request content too large (>8000)

Tags: sql, sqlfiddle

Can anyone help, please?  I cannot build a schema due to the error 'Request content too large (>8000). I noticed a comment about 'Format Code' which resolved the problem for someone else, but that option isn't available in the build schema section.

I hope someone can advise - thanks.

Comment: Make the fiddler test/example smaller?

Comment: As mentioned in [this existing answer by the developer of SQLFiddle](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11977968/300836) there's simply an 8000-character limit. Make your code shorter.

Comment: Have you tried Googling sqlfiddle alternative? See if another is better?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [is there a limit to what sql fiddle can handle? sql fiddle doesn't compile anything and returns no error messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11977441/is-there-a-limit-to-what-sql-fiddle-can-handle-sql-fiddle-doesnt-compile-anyth)